# How to separate string from numbers in R?

Tags: r, regex, stanford-nlp, data-cleaning, regex-greedy

I have a wild and crazy text file, the head of which looks like this:

```
2016-07-01 02:50:35 <name redacted> hey
2016-07-01 02:51:26 <name redacted> waiting for plane to Edinburgh
2016-07-01 02:51:45 <name redacted> thinking about my boo
2016-07-01 02:52:07 <name reda> nothing crappy has happened, not really
2016-07-01 02:52:20 <name redac> plane went by pretty fast, didn't sleep
2016-07-01 02:54:08 <name r> no idea what time it is or where I am really
2016-07-01 02:54:17 <name redacted> just know it's london
2016-07-01 02:56:44 <name redacted> you are probably asleep
2016-07-01 02:58:45 <name redacted> I hope fish was fishy in a good eay
2016-07-01 02:58:56 <name redacted> 
2016-07-01 02:59:34 <name redacted> 
2016-07-01 03:02:48 <name > British security is a little more rigorous...
```

It goes on for a while. It's a big file. But I feel like it's going to be difficult to annotate with the coreNLP library or package. I'm doing natural language processing. In other words, I'm curious as to how I would shave off, say, at least the dates, if not the dates and the names.

But I guess I would need the names, since, eventually, I would like to be able to be like, this person said this 50 times, whereas this person said this 75 times, and so on, but that's getting a little ahead of myself, probably.

Would this require a regular expression? I'm working in R.

I haven't tried anything yet, since I don't know where to start. How would I write a code in R that would selectively read for only the text? the meaningfully-put-together phrases and sentences?

Comment: Do the names have a consistent length? are they wrapped in carets as shown? is there any delimiter?

Comment: There are inconsistencies. For example, most of the time, there's no space between the end of one line and the next, but sometimes, rarely, there is. 
2016-01-27 09:15:20 <Jane Doe> Hey 2016-01-27 09:15:22. So there, there's a space between the Hey and the 2016, but that's because the space is a part of the message itself. If there's no space in the message itself, they're smooshed together like this: 2016-07-01 02:50:35 <John Doe> hey2016-07-01 02:51:26 <John Doe> waiting for plane to Edinburgh2016-07-01 02:51:45 Notice then that the hey is right next to the 2016. No space.

Comment: But there's always a space between the names with the carrots. <Jane Doe> This is Google Hangouts data btw. The structure is this. There is always a date, which is separated by a single space before the time, which is separated by a single space from the name <John Doe>, which is separated by a single space from the message itself, though, again, the message itself might or might not end on a space.

Comment: Interestingly, as soon as I paste it into an email or even these stack overflow boxes, the structure is immediately recognized, and the text boxes correctly formats the text. But, in the text file itself, it looks like this.

Comment: 2016-07-01 23:59:27 <John Doe> We're both signing off at the same time2016-07-02 00:00:04 <John Doe> :-)2016-07-02 00:00:28 <John Doe> I live you supercalagraa...phragrlous...esp..dociois2016-07-02 00:12:23 <Jane Doe> I love you :)2016-07-02 08:57:33

Comment: Having worked with the data a little more, I recognize now that, ideally, I want the data in a data.frame, with columns like, date, time, person, and comment. But that might not even be possible because of the space issue, the fact that there are inconsistencies in the data, the fact that sometimes there's a space before the start of the date (2016-07-01 23:59:27), and sometimes there's not. It seems like that would make a regular expression impossible.

Answer (score 1):

This may not need an expression, but if you wish to do that, this expression might help you to simply to that:

```
(.*)(\s<name.*)
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rpkQzB/1). You can add more boundaries if necessary.

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /(.*)(\s<name.*)/gm;
const str = `2016-07-01 02:50:35 <name redacted> hey
2016-07-01 02:51:26 <name redacted> waiting for plane to Edinburgh
2016-07-01 02:51:45 <name redacted> thinking about my boo
2016-07-01 02:52:07 <name reda> nothing crappy has happened, not really
2016-07-01 02:52:20 <name redac> plane went by pretty fast, didn't sleep
2016-07-01 02:54:08 <name r> no idea what time it is or where I am really
2016-07-01 02:54:17 <name redacted> just know it's london
2016-07-01 02:56:44 <name redacted> you are probably asleep
2016-07-01 02:58:45 <name redacted> I hope fish was fishy in a good eay
2016-07-01 02:58:56 <name redacted> 
2016-07-01 02:59:34 <name redacted> 
2016-07-01 03:02:48 <name > British security is a little more rigorous...`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Javascript was not the intended language per tags and question body. Furthermore, the regex conventions in R are not the same as those in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Using base R regular expression used in gsub function it is possible to extract each piece of information.
Suppose making this file as an example:

```
2016-07-01 02:50:35 <name1 surname1> hey
2016-07-01 02:51:26 <name1 surname1> waiting for plane to Edinburgh
2016-07-01 02:51:45 <name1 surname1> thinking about
2016-07-01 02:52:07 <name2 surname2> nothing crappy 
2016-07-01 02:52:20 <name2 surname2> plane went by pretty fast
2016-07-01 02:54:08 <name2 surname2> no idea
2016-07-01 02:54:17 <name2 surname2> just know it's london
2016-07-01 02:56:44 <name1 surname1> you are probably asleep
2016-07-01 02:58:45 <name1 surname1> I hope fish was fishy in a good eay
2016-07-01 02:58:56 <name2 surname2> x
2016-07-01 02:59:34 <name1 surname2> y
2016-07-01 03:02:48 <name2 > British security is a little more rigorous...
```

Now in R console, your read the file as a simple text and process them by a regex. Argument 2 of gsub is to extract pattern from regex

```
your_data <- readLines(your_text_file)  # Reading 
pattern <- "(.*) <(\\S*) (\\S*)>(.*)" # The regex pattern
times <- gsub(pattern,"\\1",your_data) # Get Time and date
person_name <- gsub(pattern,"\\2 \\3",your_data) # Get name
message <- gsub(pattern,"\\4",your_data) # Get message
```

Comment: I tried this, but I don't see how each of the outputs are different. They all look the same, and the regex doesn't look that different in your example either. Was this not meant to be tested out? what this only a hypothetical example? Like I was supposed to write my own regex? But I do agree with you that it should be possible. It would be nice to write a regex that would do this work, which is to say, to extract each aspect of this data into its own column.

Comment: it looks like this when I executed that code: > head (person)
[1] "ï»¿2016-01-27 09:14:40 *** Jane Doe started a video chat"                                                                                                 
[2] "2016-01-27 09:15:20 <Jane Doe> https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_WQF5kRcnpk/Vqj7J4aK1jI/AAAAAAAAAVA/GVqutPqbSuo/s0/be8ded30-87a6-4e80-bdfa-83ed51591dbf"
[3] "2016-01-27 09:15:20 <Jane Doe> Hey "

Comment: In fact, that's one of the annoying part about this data. Line 2 (though this isn't the only one like this) is way long: > test [2]
[1] "2016-01-27 09:15:20 <Jane Doe> https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_WQF5kRcnpk/Vqj7J4aK1jI/AAAAAAAAAVA/GVqutPqbSuo/s0/be8ded30-87a6-4e80-bdfa-83ed51591dbf"

Comment: > test [150]
[1] "2016-07-01 08:17:47 <John Doe> Dinner"

Answer (score 0):

Using your example pasted text, we can do the following. Note that your description of the way the text behaves when copy pasted suggests to me that there are actually newline characters `\n` in the text, but without a reproducible example it's hard to say.

1. Split the single long string into lines by splitting on the boundary before a date. If you have people regularly typing dates into messages, you can extend the pattern to include the time and name. If people are typing that into messages then it's gonna be complicated, but hopefully will only affect a few messages. This would be fixed by having line delineations.
2. Put the lines into a dataframe column and split on spaces that either precede or follow a caret `<` or `>` to split into name and message.

```r
library(tidyverse)
text <- "2016-07-01 23:59:27 <John Doe> We're both signing off at the same time2016-07-02 00:00:04 <John Doe> :-)2016-07-02 00:00:28 <John Doe> I live you supercalagraa...phragrlous...esp..dociois2016-07-02 00:12:23 <Jane Doe> I love you :)2016-07-02 08:57:33"
text %>%
  str_split("(?=\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})") %>%
  pluck(1) %>%
  enframe(name = NULL, value = "message") %>%
  separate(message, c("datetime", "name", "message"), sep = "\\s(?=<)|(?<=>)\\s", extra = "merge")
#> Warning: Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 2 rows [1,
#> 6].
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   datetime           name      message                                     
#>   <chr>              <chr>     <chr>                                       
#> 1 ""                 <NA>      <NA>                                        
#> 2 2016-07-01 23:59:… <John Do… We're both signing off at the same time     
#> 3 2016-07-02 00:00:… <John Do… :-)                                         
#> 4 2016-07-02 00:00:… <John Do… I live you supercalagraa...phragrlous...esp…
#> 5 2016-07-02 00:12:… <Jane Do… I love you :)                               
#> 6 2016-07-02 08:57:… <NA>      <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I was able to replicate what you just did (because I just cut and pasted it into R), but,when I tried it with the whole file, which is big, it only returned two broken lines, but that could be because the first and second lines of the whole file are strange:  2016-01-27 09:14:40 *** Jane Doe started a video chat
2016-01-27 09:15:20 <Jane Doe> https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_WQF5kRcnpk/Vqj7J4aK1jI/AAAAAAAAAVA/GVqutPqbSuo/s0/be8ded30-87a6-4e80-bdfa-83ed51591dbf
2016-01-27 09:15:20 <Jane Doe> Hey

Comment: The first 84 lines have this structure: > test2 [84]
[1] "2016-06-28 21:12:43 *** John Doe ended a video chat"

Comment: > test [85]
[1] "2016-07-01 02:50:35 <John Doe> hey"

Answer (score 0):

With some help, I was able to figure it out.

```
> a <- readLines ("hangouts-conversation-6.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")
> b <- "^([0-9-]{10} [0-9:]{8} )[*]{3} (\\w+ \\w+)"
> c <- gsub(b, "\\1<\\2> ", a)
> d <- "^([0-9-]{10}) ([0-9:]{8}) <(\\w+ \\w+)>\\s*(.+)$"
> e <- data.frame(date = character(),
+                     time = character(),
+                     name = character(),
+                     text = character(),
+                     stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
f <- strcapture(d, c, e)
> f <- f [-c(1),]
```

The first line was all NAs, hence the last time with the -c

Comment: And, again, this ought to work with other files of Google Hangouts data. which is where the code come from.